# Can't solve recursive math expression

Tags: c#, .net, math, console-application

I'm solving simple math task, and I have faced with some problems. I have written recursive function, but I don't get same result as in calculator. For instance *n=2,a =2*. Can anybody help me?

Task:

```
1/a + 1/(a+1) +...+ 1/(a(a+1)...(a+n))
```

Here's my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace _02__Part_A_
{
    class Program
    {
        float res = 1;

        public float func3(int n, int a)
        {
            if (n == 0)
                return 1 / (a * res);
            res = res * (a + n);
            n--;
            return func3(n, a);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program a = new Program();

            float resOFfunc3 = (float)0.5;
            string n = Console.ReadLine();
            string ak = Console.ReadLine();

            for (int nn = int.Parse(n); nn > 0; nn--)
            {
                resOFfunc3 += a.func3(nn, int.Parse(ak));
            }

            Console.WriteLine(resOFfunc3.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be rather `1/a + 1/a(a+1) +...+ 1/(a(a+1)...(a+n))`? Take a look at second part of the function.

Comment: Given your namespace I'm assuming that this is homework...

Comment: float res = 1; this needs to be reset inside the for loop before calling a.func3

Comment: There's a closed form expression for that sum in terms of the digamma function.

Comment: I believe the formula you said you are trying to solve is incorrect?.. see the first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need reset the res variable inside the for loop

```
namespace _02__Part_A_
{
    class Program
    {

        float res = 1;


        public float func3(int n,int a) {

            if (n == 0)
                return 1/(a*res);
            res = res * (a + n);
            n--;
            return func3(n,a);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program a = new Program();

            float resOFfunc3 = (float)0.5;
            string n = Console.ReadLine();
            string ak = Console.ReadLine();
            for (int nn = int.Parse(n); nn > 0; nn--)
            {
                res = 1;   // Need to add this
                resOFfunc3 += a.func3(nn, int.Parse(ak));
            }

            Console.WriteLine(resOFfunc3.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be recursive function? It can be done without recursion:

```
float result = 0;
float temp = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    temp *= a + i;
    result += 1 / temp;
}
```

I haven't tested it, but it's quite a simple algorithm so it should work.

Answer (score 2):

I have simulate your case:

1. You dont need to make **res** as global variable, otherwise why make recursive functions in first place?
2. You need 2 recursive functions

```
public float func3(int n, int a)
{
    if (a == 0) return 0;
    if (n == 0) return  a;
    return 1 * func3(n - 1, a) * (a + n);
}

public float func4(int n, int a)
{
    if (a == 0) return 0;
    if (n == 0) return 1/func3(n, a);
    return 1/func3(n, a) + func4(n - 1, a);
}
```

You just call func4.

Comment: Way to do someone else's homework for them.  I also have this fence here, I'll let you whitewash if you pay me

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using recursion, if it is not neccesary. I'd try to express it as loop, because recursion may lead to stackoverflow depending on the input (especially if the parameters are passed by value).

For example:

```
public float func(int n, int a) {
    float div = 1.0;
    float result = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
        div *= a + i;
        result += 1.0 / div;
    }
    return result;
}
```